# Figma: Can't draw a straight line using PEN Tool

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, user-experience, figma

When I'm trying to draw a line it always shows me to BEND the line.
How to draw a straight line in **FIGMA using PEN Tool** ?
Any keyboard key or anything... please help me, am a newbie.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To draw a straight line in Figma using the Pen Tool, you can do the following:

1. Select the Pen Tool from the toolbar on the left side of the screen.
2. Click on the canvas to create a starting point for the line.
3. Hold down the Shift key on your keyboard and click on a second point to create a straight line between the two points. The Shift key constrains the line to be straight, rather than curved.

Alternatively, you can draw a straight line by clicking and dragging with the Pen Tool. Just make sure to hold down the Shift key while dragging to constrain the line to be straight.